# "fatal error: fstream: No such file or directory: when uploading code to Arduino

Tags: 14.04, arduino

I am trying to upload [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunDatalogger) code to my Arduino Yun in Ubuntu and I keep getting this error:

```
Arduino: 1.5.8 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Yún"

Build options changed, rebuilding all
Using library FileIO in folder: /home/djloulou/Arduino/libraries/FileIO (legacy)

/home/djloulou/arduino-1.5.8/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_YUN -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8041 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER= -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Yun" -I/home/djloulou/arduino-1.5.8/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/djloulou/arduino-1.5.8/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/yun -I/home/djloulou/Arduino/libraries/FileIO /tmp/build8511320611227460765.tmp/sketch_dec01a.cpp -o /tmp/build8511320611227460765.tmp/sketch_dec01a.cpp.o
In file included from yun_datalogger.ino:31:0:
/home/djloulou/Arduino/libraries/FileIO/FileIO.h:12:19: fatal error: fstream: No such file or directory
 #include <fstream>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.
```

I then tried in Windows and it works fine.

So I guess it's an ubuntu problem, I think I should install a new package or something but if someone could guide me throught this I would really appreciate it because I m really new in Ubuntu and I feel helpless.

Comment: Do you have `fstream` installed on the Ubuntu system? It's telling you that the compilation cannot find that library to include. I'm personally not sure where you might be able to get it, but I could do some Googling when I get home. Try looking in `/home/djloulou/Arduino/libraries/FileIO/` and add what you find to the question.

Comment: You can search for which package contains a file by doing a search like:  `dpkg -S fstream` ... and then install that package.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all arduino files and reinstalled them and for some reason it worked. Probably i accidentally erased something in the first place.

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

fatal error: fstream: No such file or directory

By running: `dpkg -S fstream`

I get:

```
libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64: /usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream
libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/fstream.tcc
```

I could then:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64
```